# Micronaut unable to process AWS Http API gateway V2 calling Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, gateway, micronaut

```
{
              "version": "2.0",
              "routeKey": "ANY /petclinic",
              "rawPath": "/dev/petclinic",
              "rawQueryString": "",
              "headers": {
                "accept": "*/*",
                "authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI.....vdW5nIExlZSIsImNfaWQiOiI3RTZuYUY1UFEzbUE0NEtITV95bzh3IiwidV9pZC.......",
                "content-length": "0",
                "host": "sss.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                "user-agent": "curl/7.73.0",
                "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-5s069-ss",
                "x-forwarded-for": "23.240.195.204",
                "x-forwarded-port": "443",
                "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
              },
              "requestContext": {
                "accountId": "1234567890",
                "apiId": "dsdsd",
                "authorizer": {
                  "jwt": {
                    "claims": {
                      "aud": "petclinic-dev",
                      "auth_time": "1606511194",
                      "c_id": "7E6ssssM_ysw",
                      "c_type": "doctor",
                      "email": "user@petclinic.com",
                      "email_verified": "true",
                      "exp": "1606514794",
                      "firebase": "map[identities:map[email:[user@petclinic.com]] sign_in_provider:password]",
                      "iat": "1606511194",
                      "iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/petclinic-dev",
                      "name": "ss-dd, test",
                      "sub": "3fzw9dddBkibf2",
                      "u_id": "SPfrddULDQ",
                      "user_id": "3fzddddnbk0dddf2"
                    },
                    "scopes": null
                  }
                },
                "domainName": "abcdef.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
                "domainPrefix": "abcdef",
                "http": {
                  "method": "GET",
                  "path": "/dev/petclinic",
                  "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
                  "sourceIp": "23.240.195.204",
                  "userAgent": "curl/7.73.0"
                },
                "requestId": "Wrdddj_vvHcESOQ=",
                "routeKey": "ANY /petclinic",
                "stage": "dev",
                "time": "27/Nov/2020:21:32:26 +0000",
                "timeEpoch": 1606512746004
              },
              "stageVariables": {
                "StageVar": "Value"
              },
              "isBase64Encoded": false
            }


val context : Context = mock()
val handler = MicronautLambdaContainerHandler()
val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
// inputJson is the above string AWS Http API v2
handler.proxyStream(inputJson.toString().byteInputStream(), output, context)
```

I am getting the bellow error. Is Micronaut unable to parse latest AWS Http Api proxy call to lambda?

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 21, column: 14] (through reference chain: com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest["requestContext"]->com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequestContext["authorizer"]->com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.ApiGatewayAuthorizerContext["jwt"])

Comment: Can you tell what is at line 21, column 14?

Comment: Micronaut is unable to understand AWS payload --> "version": "2.0" and after digging at that line, i see that headers.authorization parsing is failing.

Comment: Hey Sreenath Venkataramanappa,

am too got into a similar issue with AWS Lambda. Wondering how were you able to solve this problem. It would be super-helpful if you have time to provide your solution to this

Regards Rakesh